# Why daemon from Android Studio is not compatible for terminal?

Tags: android-studio, gradle, intellij-idea, terminal

If we use `gradle clean build`, it will create a daemon. On the other hand, if we clean or build through Android studio, it also generates another daemon.

So, How can we make daemons compatible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, there are two main reasons to be incompatible.

- One is version mismatch of Gradle and Java. Gradle version may be
  same but JDK versions are different.
- By default, Android Studio is using embedded JDK, which most likely
  has a different version from Java installed in our machine.

**How can we make daemon compatible?**

If we use the local java in Android Studio instead of embedded JDK, this issue will be solved.

### Procedure:

1. In Android Studio, go to `Project Structure -> SDK location`.
2. Uncheck “Use embedded JDK” and
3. specify your local JDK.

### Pictorial View is given below:

**First Part:**

[image]

**Second Part:**

[image]